# Results "so far" MySQL timeout

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

MySQL, PHP page containing this line to limit the execution time to 1 second.

```
$conn->query('SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 1000');
```

Error handling to tell the user that the query is too broad and its taking too long.

```
  if ($conn->errno == 3024) {
      echo "Sorry it's taking too long, be more specific.  
    die();
    $conn->close();
  }
```

Rather than terminating the query at the point of error, is there some way to return to the user "we got x results before the query timed out"?

In other words, can we get MySQL to tell us how many results were returned before the timeout?

Is there some other way to achieve something to this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Max execution time terminates a statement during execution, before fetching of results begins. If it times out, there have been no results. If execution finishes, you can fetch results. There is no timeout to fetching.

Are you aware the `max_execution_time` is in units of milliseconds? So you are timing out the query execution at 1.0 seconds. Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention, probably allow slightly longer in production. Looking at PDO, buffering as a solution also. Thanks.